# setting the position of a button in blackberry java

Tags: blackberry

how to set the position of a button in java blackberry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position a button or any other component on a screen by creating a `Manager` class and overriding the sublayout() method. A `Manager` is kind of like a `Panel` in java i.e an area of the screen you can add components to. In the sublayout() method you should

1. set the size of the component with layoutChild()
2. set the position of the component with setPositionChild()
3. Set the overall size of the Manager with setExtent()

something like

```
    button = new ButtonField();

    HorizontalFieldManager manager = new HorizontalFieldManager(){
        protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
            int buttonWidth = button.getPreferredWidth();
            int buttonHeight = button.getPreferredHeight();
            layoutChild(button,buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
            setPositionChild(button, 0, 0);
            setExtent(width, height);
        }
    };
    manager.add(button);
```

You can override getPreferredWidth() and getPreferredHeight() for your button if you want to specify a certain width and height.

See

[Custom layout Manager](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_a_custom_layout_manager_for_a_screen.html?nodeid=800263&vernum=0)

[Manager class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html)

Comment: You can also set the position without overrides by using setMargin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526251/setmargin-method-in-blackberry/4527727#4527727